# dynamic spring bean definition for creating session factories

Tags: spring

I would like to create multiple bean definitions such as below example - where a single bean is created:

```
<bean id="sessionFactoryWorking" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:abc.hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>
```

Now I could have 1 ,2 , 3 ... n such hibernate.cfg.xml files ( abc2.hibernate.cfg.xml,abc.hibernate.cfg.xml, etc .... )

any way the Spring container can allow me to create multiple beans without me manually having to make the entries based on the number of files present

Ideal would be a map which would be keys of abc1,abc2 ...... and values would be corresponding beans

Comment: And what are you going to do with these hibernate config files? Load it or just store name of it?

Comment: I want to load it so that they can be used

Comment: Why would you need multiple session factories? Next to that what about multiple datasources you probably need and not to mention the transaction managers. My guess is you are trying to solve a problem in the wrong way.

Comment: My data is going to be all read only - so will I need a transaction manager ? ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505204/hibernate-read-only-transaction ) - about multiple SF - I have only single datasource but each SessionFactory will have different schema ( client ) - I dont thnk I can change the schema in an existing SF ?